# Ubuntu console setup for work with github repo

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I have github.com account. Till yesterday I worked with windows 7. I used Github windows client and I had got run console from it. Everything was fine.
Now I got ubuntu, then installed git via

```
$ apt-get install git
```

How can I get same console in ubuntu, Windows-look-like? So I need not enter any passwords, just commit and etc.

Comment: I'm guessing you are mostly looking for branch name on the terminal? You could try this: http://code-worrier.com/blog/git-branch-in-bash-prompt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the terminal as the console on Ubuntu and Linux, you don't need to specifically install the Git Bash terminal which is what you probably were using.